# Predicting the Order of Quadratic Residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

Using Euler's criterion we can tell if an integer is a quadratic residue modulo a prime. For example, if the prime was 11, then we could test the integers from 1 to 10 and determine that 1, 3, 4, 5, and 9 are quadratic residues in this case. If we instead found the quadratic residues by starting at 1 and squaring successive integers...

$1^2 \equiv 1$ (mod 11)

$2^2 \equiv 4$ (mod 11)

$3^2 \equiv 9$ (mod 11)

$4^2 \equiv 5$ (mod 11)

$5^2 \equiv 3$ (mod 11)

$6^2 \equiv 3$ (mod 11)

$7^2 \equiv 5$ (mod 11)

$8^2 \equiv 9$ (mod 11)

$9^2 \equiv 4$ (mod 11)

$10^2 \equiv 1$ (mod 11)

... we get the same answer but in the order: 1, 4, 9, 5, 3.

How can this order be predicted?

Comment: Interesting question. The second half is first half backwards is easy to justify, but the order of the first half doesn't seem to be except for the small ones.

Comment: I don't think it has any particular order. The Gauss sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}e^{2\pi in^2/p}$$ is known to be something like $\sqrt p$, which is also what you'd expect to get if you replaced $n^2$ with a random sequence $a_n$.